# JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'price'. Already have model.AddAttribute

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jsp

I'm making an auctions web site. I have already created a form that works for creating new auctions. But when I try to apply the exact same structure for creating bids it throws an error. I searched for the error, but most of the answers were to include "model.AddAttribute("name", new obj())" which I have already done. I think the problem might be the Entity bid, but I haven't been able to resolve it.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showProduct(Model model, @PathVariable String productId) {        
        Product product = productService.findByProductId(productId);
        model.addAttribute("bidForm", new Bid());
        model.addAttribute("product", product);
        model.addAttribute("biggestbid", bidService.findBiggestProductBid(product));
        return "product";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createBid(@ModelAttribute("bidForm") Bid bidForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        bidValidator.validate(bidForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/welcome";
        }        
        bidService.save(bidForm);
        return "redirect:/product/" + bidForm.getProduct().getProductId() ;
    }




@Entity
@Table(name = "bids")
public class Bid{   
    private String bidId;
    private float price;    
    Product product;        
    User user; 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    public String getBidId() {
        return this.bidId;
    }

    public void setBidId(String bidId) {
        this.bidId = bidId;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productid", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return this.createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return this.updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}








   <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="bidForm" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your bid</h2>

            <spring:bind path="price">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="number" step="0.01" path="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Minimum Price"
                            ></form:input>
                <form:errors path="price"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="user">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">          
                <form:input type="hidden" path="user" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="user"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>       
         <spring:bind path="product">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">          
                <form:input type="hidden" path="user" value="${product.productId}"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="product"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form:form>








javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'price' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTagInternal(BindTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.product_jsp._jspService(product_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Look like you have problem with only `price` .

Comment: It says price because it's the first input in the form. If I remove it, it accuses the next one.

Comment: Code looks fine did you debug before redirecting the page?

Comment: I'm using maven jetty for the first time, so I'm kinda newbie on debug here. But what I do know is that the error is thrown on the get page. If I comment the form I can access the product, biggestBid and bidForm with no problem. I'm not sure if this is enough... Thank you for taking some of your time to help me.